# Upgrading to react-router 5 and history

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I try to migrate from react router 3.2.6 to 5.2.1
I was used also react-router-redux. It's not compatible with react-router 5x, it seem we need to used connected-react-router

In my app.tsx

```
import {hashHistory, Router} from "react-router";
import {synchHistoryWithStore} from "react-router-redux";

async function initApp(){
  
  const store = await configureStore(
    hashHistory
  );

  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store);

  hashHistory.listen((event: any) => {

  });

  ReactDom.render(
     (
     ...
     <Router history={history}
          {routes}
     </Router>
     ....
     ),
     document.getElementById("app"),
     );

}
```

Just don't know how to migrate.
In my store by what I need to replace hashHistory?

Answer (score 1):

Your reduce/index

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware  } from "connected-react-router";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const middlewares = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

const rootReducer = (history) =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...others-reducers
  });

const generateStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./", () => {
      store.replaceReducer(rootReducer(history));
    });
  }

  return store;
};

export default generateStore;
```

Now in your App

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import generateStore, { history } from "./reducers";

const store = generateStore();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <p>mi-app<p>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```